# php/ajax query works but doesn't update

Tags: php, ajax

This is a process that I use for other ajax update functions, but for this specific instance, it doesn't want to work.  I don't know if I'm missing something in my code, or if the fact that part of the query string is a url and needs to be encoded before the AJAX plugin (don't know this and couldn't find any info on it, just brainstorming).

When I access the php script directly and echo out the query, then run it in console mode, it works fine.  When I try to access it with AJAX, I get the success response, but the entry is not updated in the DB, so I assume that means the script did not run properly.

Here is my code:

**AJAX**

```
jQuery('#nl-details').on('click','#d-cl-change', function(){

    var mls = jQuery('#d-mls').val(),
        cl = jQuery('#d-cl-input').val(),
        url = 'scripts/forms/cl/clchange.php?mls='+mls+'url='+cl;

    jQuery('#test').html(url); //This is just for me to view the URL

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            jQuery('#d-cl-save').fadeIn('200').delay('800').fadeOut('800');
            jQuery('#d-cl-url').html('<a href="'+cl+'" target="_blank">Go to Listing</a>');

        },
        error: function(){

             jQuery('#d-cl-fail').fadeIn('200').delay('800').fadeOut('800');

        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
//Generic include for MYSQL Credentials

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require('../../c.php');

$url = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,urldecode($_GET['url']));
$mls = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['mls']);

$query = "UPDATE `nht_actprop`
        SET CLLINK = '".$url."'
        WHERE MSTMLSNO = '".$mls."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

echo $query;

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` to see whether the query works out

Comment: It doesn't return any error.

Comment: `echo mysqli_error()` from the php code and try to `alert` or `console.log` the `data` in success callback.

Comment: or even you are returning the `query` from php code try to alert the `data` in success and try it in mysql console to verify.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: Tried in console, worked fine.  Issue was query string being sent from AJAX was missing `&` clause between variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have chosen a best answer already but I would just like to share with you how I would tackle this task.

I would recommend using AJAX's type option to send data via GET like this:

```
jQuery('#nl-details').on('click','#d-cl-change', function(){

    var url = 'scripts/forms/cl/clchange.php';

    jQuery('#test').html(url); //This is just for me to view the URL

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
                  mls: jQuery('#d-mls').val(),
                  url: jQuery('#d-cl-input').val()
              },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            jQuery('#d-cl-save').fadeIn('200').delay('800').fadeOut('800');
            jQuery('#d-cl-url').html('<a href="'+cl+'" target="_blank">Go to Listing</a>');

        },
        error: function(){

             jQuery('#d-cl-fail').fadeIn('200').delay('800').fadeOut('800');

        }
    });
});
```

And the best part is that you don't have to change your PHP at all

Good luck! Let me know your thoughts

Comment: Interesting data format.  Definitely cleaner.  Never done it this way.  And I suppose you don't have to change much for using `POST` (aside from the PHP script).  Any benefit to using `$_POST` vs `$_GET`?  I've asked before but never got clear answers.  also, I assume you're missing a `,` after the closing data bracket.

Comment: I am happy to see you took my answer into consideration! :) Yes I was missing a comma and it is now fixed. You are absolutely correct about the PHP side of things. As for the whole POST vs GET thing, I am still learning something new about it everyday. In short I think you should use POST because you are updating a database with your data but I think it would be worth your time to research and understand HTTP/REST or just go to this link and get some pointers http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Comment: Always looking for a better way to accomplish things.  Band-aid fixes aren't my style.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad we have similar styles. I just looked through your code more and I see that you are placing the GET variables directly inside your query; in general you are just asking to get attacked by SQL injection. I highly recommend using Prepared Statements anytime you are dealing with user data in your queries: this includes both past and present data. I say "Past" data because users probably put the data in your DB in the first place so if you are using it to generate another query then definitely "Prepare" the query. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

On this line of yor code you are missing a &

```
url = 'scripts/forms/cl/clchange.php?mls='+mls+'url='+cl;
```

I think it's supposed to be like this

```
url = 'scripts/forms/cl/clchange.php?mls='+mls+'&url='+cl;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I knew it had to be something with the AJAX.